# Cannot connect to SQL SERVER Instance on a server with multiple SQL INSTANCE

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016

Background: I have a Windows Server with 2 installed SQL 2016 Instances in it `(SQLEXPRESS,SQLLICENSED)`. `SQLLICENSED` one was installed by me.

Problem: I can connect fine using the `SQLEXPRESS` remotely on my pc but cant seem to connect to `SQLLICENSED` instance outside the local server.

I access it using `<IPAddress>\SQLLICENSED`. But got the generic connectivity error "A network-related....". I tried accessing the instance locally using the windows server where both are installed and I can connect using `<IPAddress>\SQLLICENSED` so this is a remote access issue.

Solutions that I have tried so far:

1. Start/Restart the SQL Browser service
2. Added tcp port (SQLLICENSED) to inbound and outbound

[image]

3. Turned off firewall (For testing)
4. Enabled named instances in SQL Configuration Manager

But none of this solved the issue. Would appreciate your guidance on this.

Comment: is your SQL Server Browser Service started?

Comment: "I tried accessing the instance locally using the windows server where both are installed and I cannot connect" - are you saying you cannot connect locally either? Is the service started?

Comment: @metal yes you can see that it was the first thing i tried. started then restarted again. I can remotely access another instance on the same server does i think this is not the issue

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid sorry my bad, i meant i  can connect locally just fine using the ip address with both the instances. problem is if i access it outside

Comment: if you have wireshark, you can see which port its trying to connect

Comment: Have you enabled remote connections? https://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Tridion%20Docs-v1.1.2/GUID-CF5C89EA-0918-4002-8391-80CBEDE0BB5E

Comment: Start with the [connectivity troubleshooter](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4009936/solving-connectivity-errors-to-sql-server)

Answer (score 2):

In general, following are the mandatory things when you running multiple instances on same server:

Aside, from following steps, since you're able to connect locally, verify the `Allow remote connection` is enabled from server properties[image]

**Troubleshooting steps:**

1. Ensure [TCP/IP Protocol is enable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TxnUu.jpg)
2. Make sure SQL Browser is running: this manages your inbound connections on port 1433 and recognize the name of the instance then eventually re-directed to dynamic port that's where Named Instance listening on. So you do not have to open dynamic port number at windows firewall.
3. Open Port Numbers at firewall: The re-direction activity by SQL Browser service (as mentioned in step 1) takes place with UDP Port# `1434`. So you want to enable `TCP: 1433` and `UDP:1434` at windows firewall
4. Once both steps has been done, restart SQL Browser service, you should be able to connect named instances successfully
5. In case if the issue persists, restart SQL Service, and look at SQL Error log for following message (**1533** is custom port, you should find the port number that is configured/active for instance: `SQLLICENSED`)

> Message:
>   Server is listening on [ 'any'  1533].

If you want work with [custom port configuration](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/244398/185080) enter the port number in TCP Ports, and restart SQL Service, in this case your connection should go as `<IPAddress>,<PortNumber>`

P.S: I would personally recommend to use custom ports in multiple instance setup, so that it would be more reliable and no dependency on SQL Browser service

Comment: Followed custom port configuration steps and it worked!!!! only problem now is for some reason only I can connect. Other users using the same credentials cant go in. Turning off the firewall allows them to connect though. Any idea why it would behave like that?

Comment: Whats different about the others? They're on different computers?

Comment: @TheProvost, it means, you might not added custom port for **other user's** connection, or the custom port not added into firewall rules. Anyway, you don't have to disable firewall.

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid yes

Comment: @ShekarKola custom port is not for everyone? how is that managed? i updated it using the tutorial given above but when we connect to SQL we are alll using sa (sql admin) account so im confuse how to set the customer port for other "users"

Comment: Again it's a firewall thing. Perhaps the users computers have outbound firewalls on. Or they can't even see the server. It's difficult to troubleshoot network.

Comment: Try the troubkeshooter from the client machines https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4009936/solving-connectivity-errors-to-sql-server

Comment: Hi @TheProvost, there is no configuration required at user end, all they just need to use `<IPAddress>,<CustomPort>`. i.e. if your custom port is `1533` and server IP `192.168.0.100` then every user must use in their connection `192.168.0.100,1533`. they might be still using `<IP Address>\SQLLICENSED` which is wrong since you already done custom port setup